# How do I use foreach in a tikzpicture environment with a macro input?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

I am drawing a picture in my document using a foreach loop in a tikzpicture environment, like this stripped-down example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawBoxes}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y\x\char in {#1}
    {
      \node at (\x*20pt, -\y*20pt) {\char};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\drawBoxes{1/1/a, 1/2/b, 2/1.5/c}
\end{document}
```

That produces the following result:

[image: Output]

In my real document, the text that is used in the foreach loop is coming from an optional command argument that is parsed using pgfkeys, and so I have its value in the form of a macro. When I pass a macro to the `\drawBoxes` command, though, it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawBoxes}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y\x\char in {#1}
    {
      \node at (\x*20pt, -\y*20pt) {\char};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\def \theseBoxes {1/1/a, 1/2/b, 2/1.5/c}
\drawBoxes{\theseBoxes}
\end{document}
```

produces this error message:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `a' (in '1/1/a').
>
> See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.15 \drawBoxes{\theseBoxes}

How can I fix this problem?

I see that similar questions have been asked before; so far, however, I am having a difficult time understanding the presented solutions and adapting them to my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the braces, `\foreach \y\x\char in #1`. See the first pair of examples in pgfmanual, sec. 88 "*Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement*" ([unofficial html version](https://tikz.dev/pgffor)).

Also I'm surprised that `\foreach \y\x\char in ...` works, rather than `\foreach \y/\x/\char in ...`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: In the context of my real document, removing the braces around {#1} in the foreach loop results in a different error: `Runaway argument? ... ! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete.` It seems that my stripped down example is somehow not truly representative of what's happening in my document. I will have to investigate further.

Comment: @SteveEddins Maybe caused by a blank line, which is converted to `\par`.